# VBA can't use getattributebyclass for a specific class

Tags: vba

My idea is to get the href/link from this website (https://www.fundinfo.com/en/LandingPage?apiKey=9247bf95-6dfd-3915-3c82-1c9f2ae6fe20&query=LU0329593007) and download the pdf that i need.

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBG5i.png)

So based on the screenshot above, i guess i can get the link by using getattributebyclass and class name = "fancybox". But finally nothing can be extracted.

Attach the code here. Not sure if popover hides the code/content? Can anyone help? Many thanks!

```
Sub GrabLastNames2()

'dimension (set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
Dim result As String

'start a new browser instance
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
'make browser visible
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate to page with needed data
objIE.navigate "https://www.fundinfo.com/en/LandingPage?apiKey=9247bf95-6dfd-3915-3c82-1c9f2ae6fe20&query=LU0329593007"
'wait for page to load
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

y = 1
'look at all the 'tr' elements in the 'table' with id 'myTable',
'and evaluate each, one at a time, using 'ele' variable
For Each l In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("fancy")
        result = l.outerHTML
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y) = result
        y = y + 1
        
Next
MsgBox "Done"
```

End Sub

Comment: You're using "fancy" and not "fancybox"

Comment: oh just a typo, but even if i change it to fancybox, it doesn't work too